# List all the lotus notes database

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I tried to create a lotus notes client using Java. Now, I have a problem to list all the user defined databases. What I tried to do is

```
// testing purpose
private void printAllDb() throws NotesException
{
    DbDirectory dir = session.getDbDirectory(host);
    String server = dir.getName();
    if(server.equals(""))
    {
        server = "Local";
    }

    System.out.println("database direcory list on server (" + server + ")");
    Database db = dir.getFirstDatabase(DbDirectory.DATABASE);

    do
    {
        System.out.println("file name: " + db.getFileName().toUpperCase() + " - " + db.getTitle());

    } while((db = dir.getNextDatabase()) != null);

}
```

However, the program will throw the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" NotesException: Server access denied
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHelper.read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesExceptionHolder._read(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.iiop.RepImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.priv.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.corba._IDbDirectoryStub.getFirstDatabase(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.cso.DbDirectory.getFirstDatabase(Unknown Source)
at nz.co.sylresearch.sylsearch.agents.lotusnotes.LotusNotesAPIHandler.printAllDb(LotusNotesAPIHandler.java:58)
at nz.co.sylresearch.sylsearch.agents.lotusnotes.LotusNotesAPIHandler.main(LotusNotesAPIHandler.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is pretty clear.  You are getting an access denied error to the server. The tricky part now is figuring out why.

You should start with making sure the username and password used to create the session object is correct. Then make sure that user has access to the server and has access to run Java code on the server.  You'll have to check the server document in the Directory for that.

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you tell me which server document I should go for? I tried create a session by using createSessionWithFullAccess but it just not work and throw a class not found exception

Comment: He is referring to the server document for 'host' (whatever the real name is -- that's just your variable name, and we don't know the value) in the Domino Directory (i.e., the names.nsf database), which you can most easily find using the Domino Administrator client.

Comment: From the doc, I believe that createSessionWithFullAccess requires the password that corresponds to a Notes ID file. You are using the ncso.jar file, which uses IIOP/CORBA to talk to Domino, and therefore it does not require (and cannot use) a Notes ID file. So I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think that means that you cannot use CreateSessionWithFullAccess with ncso.jar.